# django-filebrowser returns system path instead of media URL

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

```
Tests: OK
Version: FileBrowser 3.5.7, Grappelli 2.5.3, Django 1.6.10
```

Filebrowser renders weird image URLs. For instance, `/admin/filebrowser/browse/` renders this:

```
<td class="fb_thumbnail">            
    <a href="/Users/mike/Projects/oi/adx/public/media/0b8d1ac8bb874a16c292260348065e3c.jpg" class="fb_viewlink"><img src="/Users/mike/Projects/oi/adx/public/media/_versions/0b8d1ac8bb874a16c292260348065e3c_admin_thumbnail.jpg" title="View Image"></a>            
</td>
```

It creates thumbnails, but for some reason the URLs are file paths.

My settings:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE= 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = '/Users/mike/Projects/oi/adx/public/media/'
FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/mike/Projects/oi/adx/public/media/'
FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS_BASEDIR = '/Users/mike/Projects/oi/adx/public/media/_versions'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/mike/Projects/oi/adx/public/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/mike/Projects/oi/adx/public/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY`](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#directory-relative-to-storage-location) is relative to `FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT` so make it empty:

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = ''
```

Or restrict to some dir:

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'uploads/'
```

Also note that `FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT` and `FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_URL` are the same as `MEDIA_ROOT`/`MEDIA_URL`.  This is the default setting and you can safely delete these lines from `settings.py`.